# Postgresql copy command not finding file

Tags: postgresql

when running:

```
~/fidelity/releases/20220907033831$ ls -a
.
..
.browserslistrc  
221005_users_all.csv
_private
```

the presence of a file is confirmed.

However, when launching a postgresql command

```
psql fidelity_development
COPY users (id,migrated_id,[...]) FROM '~/fidelity/releases/20220907033831/221005_users_all.csv'  DELIMITER ';' CSV HEADER;
```

The response is unexpected:
`ERROR:  could not open file "~/fidelity/releases/20220907033831/221005_users_all.csv" for reading: No such file or directory`

What am I missing to determine why postgresql cannot see this file?

*note* this directory was also simlinked as `fidelity/current` and the same result was obtained when referring to that directory for the file, whereas bash sees it.

Comment: Try to use `\copy` as `copy` is server based and `\copy` is client based.

Comment: that worked.  however, I clearly do not grasp the subtlety of how being on the server that hosts the database and connecting to it, I would find myself in a 'client-based' contest.

Comment: in case DB server is on the same machine `COPY` command handles the path from the scope of a location of a DB server - that could cause the problem with finding the file. You used tilde meaning the current directory of a user. DB server might run under a different user account.

Comment: That was quite useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `\COPY` command as this one is client based and handles the local path correctly.

While `COPY` is server based and this could cause issues finding your file.